# Testing for toLocaleString support

Tags: javascript, safari

I use `toLocaleString` to format a British job salary, passing in options for currency like this:

```
tempSalary = parseInt(salary).toLocaleString('en-gb', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP'});
```

I know that this doesn't get implemented properly in Safari, but could I check in advance to output something else? As per [the MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), could I check for locales and options arguments, and if unsupported, don't bother with the script?

I'd rather check for support than just check whether using Safari (as IE10- also doesn't support it fully).

Comment: You can try testing for the *Intl* object as start. If not supported, the host doesn't support the internationalisation spec under which the options for *toLocaleString* are defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ECMA-402](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-13.2.1) says that to support options for *Number.prototype.toString*, an implementation must:

1. Be consistent with ECMAScript Ed 5.1 and its successors
2. Extend the built–in *Number.prototype*
3. Implement an *Intl* global object
4. Support the *Intl.NumberFormat* constructor

So based on that, a test for support is:

```
if (typeof Intl == 'object' && typeof Intl.NumberFormat == 'function') {

  // toLocaleString with options supported

} else {

  // host dependent

}
```

As a function:

```
function toLocaleStringSupportsOptions() {
  return !!(typeof Intl == 'object' && Intl && typeof Intl.NumberFormat == 'function');
}
```

It must be tested widely of course. It works in the few more popular browsers I tested, some with and some without *Intl.NumberFormat* support.

However there may be bugs within implementations. The only one I can think of that might occur is that some may not return expected values for *typeof*, even though they are required to (e.g. in the past there have been browsers that return 'unknown' instead of 'object' or 'object' instead of 'function'). Also, ECMA-262 ed 3 implementations are not required to throw an error if an *options* parameter is provided, so detection based on *try..catch* may fail in those hosts.

The following is a more tolerant version (but I would use the above until I discovered a host where it's required):

```
function toLocaleStringSupportsOptions() {
  return !!(typeof Intl != 'undefined' && Intl && typeof Intl.NumberFormat != 'undefined');
}
```

Comment: Yes, works as expected and simple to implement. Thanks, this is straightforward so best answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make a function as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments) suggests. And handle the error accordingly.

```js
function toLocaleStringSupportsLocales() {
  var number = 0;
  try {
    number.toLocaleString('i');
  } catch (e) {
    return e​.name === 'RangeError';
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not certain to work in browsers prior to ES5, as they aren't required to throw an error if an *options* argument is provided.

Comment: this method is not working for current safari version (9.1.1) .See screenshots: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160705/b9i8z3a7.png and http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160705/trguc6wh.png